# Fritztrainer on Linux

Tags: software, linux

What is the best way to use Fritztrainer DVDs/videos on Linux? Is there anyone who is using them on Linux now? Is there any free tool to run Fritztrainer DVDs natively?

Comment: Nobody with Linux? :'(

Comment: I have attempted a response. A bounty might get a better response but is - judging by what I found - unlike to lead to a native solution.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe There is nothing better than what you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Over the years, this question has been asked several times on other forums, but I am not aware of a purely native solution.

According to this [discussion on chess.com from 2013](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/fritz-training-videos-under-linux), some people have tried [**Wine**](https://www.winehq.org/), which is "a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, Mac OSX, & BSD" (quoted from the Wine website). People have reported varying levels of success, depending on the version of Wine and the distro they were using.

In an [older discussion (started in 2009)](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-equipment/chessbase-on-linux), someone suggested using [**VirtualBox**](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and installing Windows in it. Unlike Wine, this requires Windows installation media and a Windows licence.

**Update**: [Proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)#Proton), released by Valve (the developers of Steam) in August 2018, should enable Linux users to run Windows games directly through Steam for Linux. [Fritz XIV for Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/276750/Fritz_Chess_14/) and [FritzChess 15 for Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/427480/FritzChess_15/) have been available since September 2014 and February 2016, respectively. I don't know whether this also solves the issue of using the Fritztrainer DVDs.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will upvote but not accept the answer in order to leave room for a miracle solution : )

Comment: I think using Wine would be the way to go. I managed to run several old games (as Baldur's Gate series) on my Ubuntu using Wine. Wine works fine running Windows applications, and most problems (at least in my own experience) are related to the use of lowercase/uppercase in file names. For example changing all names to lowercase solved my problems with BG.

Comment: Actually, I knew all the methods mentioned in this topic before asking the question. Nonetheless, the answer is valuable. I am hoping for an answer with a method which I don't know yet.

Answer (score 1):

Wine or Virtualbox, as already mentioned, use to be the options when you wish to run Windows programs on Linux. Wine use to be the best option but it can be a challenge and a pain sometimes to make it work properly with the desired windows application. There is a commercial alternative called [Crossover](https://www.codeweavers.com/) which basically is Wine with some more user friendly configuration scripts etc. I don't know how much better than Wine it is but if you are interested there is a free trail you can try out there before bying.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning Crossover.